# generating white gaussian noise in matlab using two different functions

Tags: matlab, noise, gaussian, stochastic

I want to know the difference between the two Gaussian noises generated below? Which one is white and how can i make the other one white?

```
y=wgn(1,10000,0)
```

and

```
y=randn(1,10000);
```

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! They are both white. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: because it is not mentioned in the matlab help that they are white. i believe they are just samples of a gaussian distribution.

Comment: thank u Peter.im happy to be here.actually i'm having a hard time distinguishing the difference between whitness of samples and their gaussianity.i believe some samples generated of a specific distribution are not white(or uncorrelated) by them self  and we shoud white them

Comment: `randn` produces independent samples of a Gaussian random variable, which happens to be the same as Gaussian white noise. Note that this white noise is actually filtered to fit in the bandwidth specified by the sampling rate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **white** noise sequence is one for which each (random) element is uncorrelated from every other element:
$$
E[y[n]y[m]] = \left \{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 & \mbox{for } n\not=m\\
\sigma_y^2 & \mbox{for } n = m
\end{array}
\right . \\= \sigma_y^2 \delta[n-m]
$$
where $\sigma^2_y$ is the variance of $y$.

Note that I am assuming (because of the whiteness) that the signal is zero mean.

The whiteness of a signal says **nothing** about the distribution of its values.  To know something about that, *Gaussianity* or some other distribution needs to be invoked.

The functions `wgn` and `randn` both produce **white,** **Gaussian** noise sequences.

Calling the function `rand` would produce a **white**, **uniformly distributed** noise sequence.

Comment: A white noise sequence is one for which each s̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶i̶s̶t̶i̶c̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶i̶n̶d̶e̶p̶e̶n̶d̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ __(random) element is statistically independent from every other element__

Comment: @toes What is the impact of your suggested change? Feel free to edit and have it reviewed.

Comment: I misquoted in my previous comment. Should've read ...is uncorrelated from every other element... Post is corrected now anyway

Answer (score 2):

wgn() is specifically meant to create a white noise with a predefined power levels while randn() is meant to generate normally distributed random numbers WITHOUT specifying the power. You will have to scale the values generated from randn() to meet the desired noise power level. Basically wgn() (usually used with awgn()) makes your life easier if you want to create a noise with known power level.

Hope this helps!